# SharePoint 2010, CMIS Integration, and Claims-based Authentication

Tags: authentication, cmis

I have an application that integrates with content systems like Alfresco and IBM FileNet P8. Now, we have an SP 2010 system we are trying to integrate. The SP system is secured via Claims-based authentication and the CMIS Producer has been added to the 2010 server. Still, unless we change security to NTLM, we cannot get connected.

Are there any gotchas, known issues, or advice for making this work?

Answer (score 1):

I do not have hands on time with the CMIS connector however

It looks like 2010 only supports Basic and digest authentication, and is not built to utilize the claims to windows token service.  It looks like you do indeed need windows auth to use the connector.

2013 looks like they added support for a variety of schemes: Anonymous AuthN, Basic AuthN, NTLM AuthN, Digest AuthN, Kerberos Protocol Transitioning/Constrained Delegation, Windows-Claims, Claims MultiAuth, and Claims Mixed Mode.

It looks like [@SteveB](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/users/3497/steve-b) fought with this [issue](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/41984/cmis-producer-service-not-working) and never got it resolved.  He is pretty active on this site, it might be worth it to reach out to him and see if he has a valid workaround (probably a third party or custom CMIS connector).